# How to extend a class is Python

Tags: python, class, oop, import, extend

I am new to learning Python. I have been writing an array class and creating lots of methods to manipulate the array. It has been very interesting. To expound on this, I created a grid class to create a two-dimensional array. But now I am stuck on this instruction:

"Develop a matrix class that uses the built-in operators for arithmetic (this is for matrix arithmetic). The matrix class should extend the grid class."

I am confident in how to figure out the arithmetic between the grids. However, I don't understand the part that says to extend the grid class in the matrix class. Just playing around with it, I have this code in my matrix class:

```
from grid import Grid

class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, rows, columns, fillValue):
        self.data = Grid(rows, columns, fillValue)
```

And here is my grid class:

```
"""
File: grid.py
"""

from arrays import Array

class Grid(object):
    """Represents a two-dimensional array."""

    def __init__(self, rows, columns, fillValue = None):
        self.data = Array(rows)
        for row in range(rows):
            self.data[row] = Array(columns, fillValue)

    def getHeight(self):
        """Returns the number of rows."""
        return len(self.data)

    def getWidth(self):
        "Returns the number of columns."""
        return len(self.data[0])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Supports two-dimensional indexing with [][]."""
        return self.data[index]

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of the grid."""
        result = ""
        for row in range(self.getHeight()):
            for col in range(self.getWidth()):
                result += str(self.data[row][col]) + " "
            result += "\n"
        return result

def main():
    g = Grid(10, 10, 1)
    print(g.getHeight())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am confused about how to properly extend the grid class within the matrix class. I understand the importance for the import statement; however, I am a bit confused on how to write my constructor properly so that this statement

```
m1 = Matrix(3, 3, 2)
    print(m1)
```

will pass those parameters to the grid class and create a grid correctly. For example, the print statements gives this output: `<__main__.Matrix object at 0x000001CD65A77970>` If I am understanding this correctly, that should have printed an actual grid of numbers, and I am at a loss as to why it is not. Any thoughts sure would help me out!!!

Comment: The phrase ‘extend the grid class’ is usually taken to mean ‘derive from Grid’. That is: ‘class Matrix(Grid):’

Comment: Ahh thank you. Getting rid of my __init__ method and implementing the class Matrix(Grid): did the trick. Thank you!!!